# View bottom border gives different color

Tags: reactjs, react-native

hello I am new to react native I am facing an issue I need a border which  separate different  for this I have created an empty  View

```
<View
                  style={{
                    borderBottomColor: '#787878',
                    borderBottomWidth: 0.2,
                  }}
                />
```

but its give different color as you seen in image below
[image]
here is my code below

```
<View
                style={{
                  height: '75%',
                  borderRadius: 5,
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                }}>
                <List
                  tlr={4}
                  trr={4}
                  height={42}
                  Bg="white"
                  titleOne="WALK to gogo point to take the ride"
                  titleTwo="ello"
                  image={require('../assests/walk.png')}
                  color="#888D9B"
                  mt={0}
                />
                <View
                  style={{
                    borderTopColor: '#787878',
                    borderTopWidth: 0.6,
                  }}
                />

                <List
                  mt={0}
                  height={42}
                  Bg="white"
                  titleOne="Pakistan science club"
                  image={require('../assests/metro.png')}
                  color="#888D9B"
                />
                <View
                  style={{
                    borderBottomColor: '#787878',
                    borderBottomWidth: 0.2,
                  }}
                />
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                  <View style={{width: '50%'}}>
                    <List
                      height={42}
                      Bg="white"
                      titleOne="CD-70"
                      image={require('../assests/gogobike.png')}
                      color="#888D9B"
                    />
                  </View>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      borderRightColor: '#787878',
                      borderRightWidth: 0.2,
                    }}
                  />
                  <View style={{width: '50%'}}>
                    <List
                      height={42}
                      Bg="white"
                      titleOne="Referral code"
                      image={require('../assests/discount.png')}
                      color="#888D9B"
                    />
                  </View>
                </View>
```

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer which helped you and seems most appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `borderWidth` to any fraction (like 0.2, 0.5, 1.2) it might give unexpected behavior.

See this:https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12401#issuecomment-286756120

So either set `borderWidth` as integer or `StyleSheet.hairlineWidth`

```
borderBottomWidth = StyleSheet.hairlineWidth
```

import Stylesheet first, as:

```
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
```

**StyleSheet.hairlineWidth is the best way to go for a very thin borderWidth.**
https://reactnative.dev/docs/stylesheet#hairlinewidth

Comment: i considered but its not working it gives abnormal behavior too

Comment: Do you have any overlapping borders? That might increase thickness.

Answer (score 1):

For separation of different sections, I would recommend using `divider` from `react-native-elements` [this](https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/divider/).

However the color difference you see here is due to the different `borderWidth` (`0.6` and `0.2` ). Try using a consistent `borderWidth` or  `StyleSheet.hairlineWidth`.